# How to make my program run faster for larger string inputs?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to operate on the number of occurences of each element and subtract an integer from it.
For now this is my code it takes a lot of time when the inputsize becomes very large.I have used Counter and it performs worse with it.

```
s=input()
C=int(input())
total=0
for i in set(s):
    if s.count(i)>C:
        total=total+s.count(i)-C
print(total)
```

Comment: Using `Counter` I get about 6x speedup, so I don't understand your claim that it would perform worse. Can you support this with concrete numbers and a benchmark test?

Comment: I think it's pretty hard to beat the performance of `Counter` since it iterates over the input string only once. Your solution iterates over the string `N + 1` times where `N = len(s)` (actually if performs even `2*N + 1` iterations but the additional `N` are unnecessary). Given that this string is large, as you describe in your question, this significantly decreases performance.

Answer (score 2):

You have [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

`Counter` is a subclass of dictionary to count distinct elements. And I think you don't care about its keys, but you need only count values.

```py
from collections import Counter

s = input()
C = int(input())
total = sum(c - C for c in Counter(s).values() if c > C)
print(total)
```

explanation:

- `Counter(s).values()` gives iterator for count values.
- `(c - C for c in ...)` makes generator object with substracting and filtering.
- `sum(...)` returns sum of it.

Comment: Actually it should be `max(c - C, 0)`.

Comment: @a_guest Not necessarily, because of the filter.

Comment: @Tomalak Which filter?

Comment: @a_guest Well, the `if c > C` that was in there before @Boseong edited it out...

Comment: I fixed. Sorry for that.